# Character Encoding Error in File

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a input where the user can (and has and will always) paste data in from MSword; in particular characters like `&copy;` `&reg;` `&trade;`

When I add the value to the database system using `html_entity_decode($foo, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

When I read from the database system it renders on the screen fine, but when I write the data to a file (using `fputscsv`) and attach that to an email the resulting csv file (opened in Excel) it comes out like **CopyrightÂ©**.

Any idea on how to get it in the right format for the file?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the original user data is. Are they putting the © symbol directly or are they putting in `&copy;` in the content?

Comment: they are putting the © directly in (pasting from word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found; it turned out to be a character encoding problem (I'm blaming Microsoft, as it is fine when you open the file in Notepad++).

When adding the data to the file convert the character encoding of the data using [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).
Example;

```
foreach ($data_row as $k => $cell) {
    $data_row[$k] = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing byte order mark to the file before writing CSV string.

```
$byte_order_mark = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
$contents = $byte_order_mark . $csv_string;
file_put_contents( $path_to_csv_file );
```